# Can T4MVC work in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, t4mvc

I've read around on this issue but I'm unclear if it's possible to get T4MVC working with VB.NET. I'm using T4MVC and ASP.NET MVC4.

I downloaded and installed T4MVCVB from [this link](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/releases/view/41582) and I've already installed the T4MVC package. I've renamed my helper from `MVC` to `MVCH`

My current problem is that when I try to use it within a View:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", MVCH.Home.Index)
```

I get this:

[image: Error]

If I try to use it from a controller, such as:

```
Return View(MVCH.Home.Index)
```

It works no problem.

Has anyone been able to get T4MVC working with VB.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

T4MVCVB has not really been kept up to date with T4MVC, though I think it should still work. But note that when using it, you should *not* also import the T4MVC NuGet package. Instead, just use T4MVCVB by itself. I suspect that's why you're getting conflicts.

Comment: I had imported the NuGet package. Uninstalled it and now everything works. Thanks!